# How to design network with high availability in a multilevel small workplace

Tags: ethernet, design, networking, power-over-ethernet

I want to create a network in my work 4 floors 50m2*4 workplace.
Requirements are simple:

1. Share internet ( < 20mb/s ADSL) while blocking someone from abusing download speed for long period. (Throttle him if he downloads continuously for 5mins+ !)
2. WiFi coverage to 3 floors 60m2
3. Allow all devices to access local servers (2 ubuntu servers 1 running the web server and other git servers)

I have no experience in networks and I googled and found many solutions.

First, the problem encountered while planning for such low traffic network is should I use
1. Business grade 2. Consumer grade products ??

Is it worth the huge price difference?
Do I have to buy a network controller? If all I need is a single TCP/IP network?

What I have in mind?

1. Poe router
2. Poe switch 8ports * 3
3. Poe access point 2 on each floor (6)

I was thinking I can take 1 cat6 cable from the router into a switch.
Then take a cable into my 2 servers and 1 to a switch in a floor above it.

Take 2 cables from the 2nd-floor switch into my 2 access point in that floor and one cable to floor above. And so on until I cover all floors.

The network will be used by around 20-40 device most traffic is HTTP web traffic for our local server (git server & web server both internal)

Can someone tell me if I'm thinking straight or not?

When so you chose to use a switch on each level, vs single 28port switch on the first floor?

Since I will still do all civil work anyway, is Poe worth it?
Or I should save and just take a power cable to run along with all cat6 ducts from floor 1 upward?

If I ever decided to use phones or cameras on this network would it work or there are things to consider first?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Network Engineering!  We hope you will become a contributing member of this community.  While all the questions you ask are valid ones, they tend to elicit opinions, which are, sadly, off-topic here.  However, you can ask these questions on [Network Engineering Chat] (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations), where they are very welcome.